# MongoDB- shell default configuration

Tags: mongodb

Am new to Mongo DB trying to find the conf file to set up default sever to connect when opening the shell.

Am using:
Windows 10 , shellplus-4.2.5 and connecting to Cloud mongo DB with below command

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://{SERVER}/test"  --username admin
```

I can not see any config file available. How to set default or Configuration that need to be used

```
 db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts');
{ "argv" : [ ], "parsed" : { }, "ok" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using MongoDB Atlas, you do not need to set up a server. Atlas *is* the server.

No configuration is needed to connect to Atlas beyond the correct URI, as described in [the documentation](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/mongo-shell-connection/).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using MongoDB Atlas, then you Atlas platform does not the access to the configuration file. In Atlas their is default configuration available which is available on all clusters and users cannot make any changes to the configuration file.

However, in case you are using our own hosted MongoDB deployment then you can access the default MongoDB configuration file on the following path:

- On Linux, a default /etc/mongod.conf configuration file is included when using a package manager to install MongoDB.
- On Windows, a default /bin/mongod.cfg configuration file is included during the installation.
- On macOS, a default /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf configuration file is included when installing from MongoDB’s official Homebrew tap.

For more information please refer the documentation : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html

and it is not mandatory to use the default mongod.conf file on the above mentioned path. You can make your custom configuration file and can run you own hosted deployment with the following command:

`mongod -f mongod1.conf`

Please ping me in case you need more information